# Select Dictionary from list of Dictionaries and make some updates

Tags: python

I have following list of dictionaries.

```
  player = [{"Cate": "EU91", "Points": 256, "good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU93", "Points": 193, "Good": 3,  },
            {"Cate": "FU91", "Points": 216, "Good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU95", "Points": 256, "good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU93", "Points": 193, "Good": 3,  },
            {"Cate": "FU99", "Points": 216, "Good": 1,  }]
```

In the above dictionary, I want to store the particular dictionary to some variable based on the "Cate" value equal to EU91 or FU91. What I have tried is:

```
if any(d['Cate'] == 'EU91' or d['Cate'] == 'FU91'  for d in player):
     print('U91 category exists')
```

In the above code, I Only check whether EU91 or FU91 is present or not. I need to store the particular dictionary (Where "Cate" value equal to EU91 or FU91) in some variable and also update that selected dictionaries like following:

```
list = [ {"Cate": "U91", "Points_A": 256, "good": 1 }, {"Cate": "U91","Points_B": 256, "good": 1 } ]
```

Explanation: If both EU91 and FU91 are present, then Update that particular dictionary of "Cate" to "U91" then update "Points" to "Points_A" for EU91 and "Points" to "Points_B" for FU91.

I expect the result:

```
var = [{"Cate": "U91", "Points_A": 256, "good": 1 },{"Cate": "U91","Points_B": 256, "good": 1}]
```

I hope you all understand my question.
Any Ideas?Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple for loop with if condition.

**Ex.**

```
player = [{"Cate": "EU91", "Points": 256, "good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU93", "Points": 193, "Good": 3,  },
            {"Cate": "FU91", "Points": 216, "Good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU95", "Points": 256, "good": 1,  },
            {"Cate": "EU93", "Points": 193, "Good": 3,  },
            {"Cate": "FU99", "Points": 216, "Good": 1,  }]
result = []
for x in player:
    if x['Cate'] == 'EU91':
        x['Points_A'] = x.pop('Points')
    elif  x['Cate'] == 'FU91':
        x['Points_B'] = x.pop('Points')

    if "Points_A" in x or "Points_B" in x:
        x['Cate'] = "U91"
        result.append(x)

print(result)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'Cate': 'U91', 'good': 1, 'Points_A': 256}, {'Cate': 'U91', 'Good': 1,
 'Points_B': 216}]
```